# Calculating max peak current at different conditions

Tags: led, current, pwm, maximum-ratings

I have an IR LED (IR383), and I want to power it with 5v@38KHz. I'm actually calculating the resistor so I need the LED's maximum current. In the datasheet, it says that it accepts 100mA continuous and 1A peak, this being at Pulse Width <= 100uS and 1% duty. How can I calculate, using this information, the peak maximum current with my 38KHz (50% duty)?

(1/38KHz = 26.3157895uS)

Comment: @delanymichael The thing is that, at 100mA, the light can't reach far enough. Also, I can't be sure that I will be able to power it at 1A with that statement because it says 100uS@1% duty and I need 26.3uS@50% duty.

Comment: So at what current does it reach far enough?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat didn't test because I don't know how high can the current be and I don't want to burn them.

Comment: You need to include a link to your IR LED.  You need to include the distance you want to reach.  And sadly, you are going to have to experiment.  As in sacrifice IR LED's to the electron gods.

Comment: @delanymichael Yes, I know. But my resources and physical space on the PCB won't allow me to put more than one LED. That's why I'm asking. BTW, Why are you being so aggressive?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat: I want to reach ideally 1.75m with my [LED](http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/IR383.pdf), but I don't think I can reach that far. That's why I'm trying to know how far the maximum is.

Comment: So the applications include:․Infrared remote control units with high power requirement, so I don't think 1.75m is a problem.

Comment: Sorry lol it's really 3.5m because I have to detect a reflection at 1.75m. The thing is, it doesn't work with 100mA, so for remote controllers, it must be more.

Comment: What have you been able to work out from the datasheet? I see a simple diode model trivially developed; therefore the ability to work out the range of voltages for any range of currents; the ability to work out a hoped-for action integral for the LED which you must stay under; and the ability to work out the degraded average power allowable when pulsing. Of course, you'd still need to verify since the manufacturer didn't spec their parts for your use.

Comment: To save some searching moments that Iaka failed to save, the datasheet is here: [Everlight 5mm Infrared LED, T-1 3/4, IR383](http://www.everlight.com/file/ProductFile/201407061535229877.pdf). There's enough in the datasheet to advance an educated guess or two towards bounding the problem better.

Comment: So how can I do it? Do I have to calculate the average current in the example and compare it to my model's?